# Is using long where statements bad coding style?

Tags: haskell, random, coding-style, where-clause

I am a Haskell newbie, so I don't know a lot about the coding style. I have a function that chains a lot of random generators. Is this kind of code considered in bad style, wherein I have ~10 lines after a `where` statement? If so, what are the alternatives?

```
#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell
{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax #-}
module Main where

makeDummy :: RandomGen g ⇒ [String] → FilePath → g → (FilePath, g)
makeDummy words root gen0 = (fullPath, gen7)
  where
      (numWordsInTitle, gen1) = randomR (1 :: Int, 4 :: Int) gen0 -- unused
      (title, gen2) = randomChoice words gen1
      (year, gen3) = randomR (1800 :: Int, 2100 :: Int) gen2
      (resNum, gen4) = randomChoice ["1080", "720", "480"] gen3
      (resLetter, gen5) = randomChoice ["P", "p", "i", "I"] gen4
      res = resNum ++ resLetter
      (shuffled, gen6) = shuffle [title, show year, resNum ++ resLetter] gen5
      (fileExt, gen7) = randomChoice [".mkv", ".mp4", ".ogv", ".srt", ""] gen6
      path = (++ fileExt) $ intercalate " " shuffled
      fullPath = root </> path
```

As this could be a somewhat subjective subject, please restrain answers to relfect the Haskell community code style norms, rather than personal opinion/aesthetics.

I am aware of the possibility of using `getStdRandom`, but would like to use a pure function here, preferrably.

Comment: "Is this kind of code considered in bad style, wherein I have ~10 lines after a where statement". Not necessarily, but it's a good rule of thumb to not have names be in scope places where they're not used. What you're really trying to do is function composition (in this case a fancier form of function composition with `State` would be appropriate). So I guess if you're finding yourself binding names in a where clause and using them from top to bottom, realize you might be looking for some sort of composition

Comment: @jberryman Could you perhaps provide an example of some other sort of composition using State?

Comment: Well, the specific sort of composition involved is not `(.)` but rather `<=<`, from `Control.Monad`. It chains together monadic computations. In this case, as in many others, it's better to string things together more explicitly in a `do` expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yup! This is the sort of situation where a state monad (or even, more specifically, a randomness monad) is really handy. These let you chain together computations that all transform some sort of state, in this case the random seed. See, for example, `Control.Monad.State` or look for `MonadRandom`.

Comment: I should've been more specific! I have edited my question. This is a great answer, but I would prefer to do this purely. Is there a better way to chain this random generation in a pure function?

Comment: @Langston The `State` monad *is* pure, it is just a newtype wrapper around a pure function. [`MonadRandom`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom) can be used either purely or with `IO` as you wish.

Comment: @Langston `g -> (a, g)` is an useful pattern to recognise in type signatures - it should immediately bring `State` to mind. And `State` is pure, as Ørjan has just said.

Comment: duplode, Ørjan, thank you for the clarification! dfeuer, thanks for the answer! Could any of you post an example of how to use the State monad here?

Answer (score 9):

By request, here's how to rewrite the function using `State` in the most direct way. Note that the top level type signature hasn't changed.

```
makeDummy :: RandomGen g ⇒ [String] → FilePath → g → (FilePath, g)
makeDummy words root = runState $ do
    numWordsInTitle <- state $ randomR (1 :: Int, 4 :: Int) -- unused
    title <- state $ randomChoice words
    year <- state $ randomR (1800 :: Int, 2100 :: Int)
    resNum <- state $ randomChoice ["1080", "720", "480"]
    resLetter <- state $ randomChoice ["P", "p", "i", "I"]
    let res = resNum ++ resLetter
    shuffled <- state $ shuffle [title, show year, resNum ++ resLetter]
    fileExt <- state $ randomChoice [".mkv", ".mp4", ".ogv", ".srt", ""]
    let path = (++ fileExt) $ intercalate " " shuffled
    let fullPath = root </> path
    return fullPath
```

More usually, you would avoid most of the uses of `state $` by defining the utility functions such as `randomChoice` to already be in the `State` monad. (This is more or less part of what the `MonadRandom` package does.)

Answer (score 3):

Excellent answers already by dfeuer and Ørjan Johansen, but I'll throw my few cents in anyway.  I would recommend the following:

1. First and foremost, use this as an opportunity to study the `State` monad.
2. But don't actually use the state monad for the solution, use the [`MonadRandom`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom) package instead.  The `Rand` type from there is a specialized `newtype` wrapper around `State` with custom operations for randomness, and makes code easier to read.
3. There are a bunch of bits here that would benefit from separating these two concerns:

   - Generating random values.
   - Combining them into bigger results.

For example, I would start by splitting this into its own function as follows:

```
makeFullPath :: [String] -> FilePath -> String -> FilePath
makeFullPath words root fileExt = 
    root </> (intercalate " " words ++ fileExt)
```

Since that's the result you're returning, let's call this the "main" thing that you're trying to do—most of the other code is subordinate to feeding random arguments into that function.  But that splits into two parts: (a) generating the random "words", and (b) shuffling them.   Let's write a function for (b) first, assuming you already have the words but not shuffled:

```
makeShuffledPath 
  :: RandomGen g => [String] -> FilePath -> String -> Rand g FilePath
makeShuffledPath words root fileExt = do
    shuffled <- shuffle words
    fileExt <- uniform [".mkv", ".mp4", ".ogv", ".srt", ""]
    return (makeFullPath shuffled root fileExt)
```

(Note that I've assumed that `shuffle` has been rewritten to use `MonadRandom`.  Also, I haven't tested any of this code, there are probably dumb mistakes in it.  But that's all an exercise for you!)

The generation of a random resolution looks like a complex enough meaningful unit to split apart as well:

```
randomResolution :: RandomGen g => Rand g String
randomResolution = do
    resNum <- uniform ["1080", "720", "480"]
    resLetter <- uniform ["P", "p", "i", "I"]
    return (resNum ++ resLetter)
```

Now, tying it all together:

```
makeDummy :: RandomGen g => [String] -> FilePath -> Rand g FilePath
makeDummy words root = do
    title <- uniform words
    year <- getRandomR (1800 :: Int, 2100 :: Int)
    resolution <- randomResolution
    makeShuffledPath [title, show year, resolution] root

runDummy :: RandomGen g => [String] -> FilePath -> g -> (FilePath, g)
runDummy words root = runRand (makeDummy words root)
```